# Why does deleting host account solve the #0088 error?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, server, nameserver

To change the host, I switch my nameserver to default in my registrar. However, the new host keeps saying that my domain is hosted on other host and refuses to continue. I have also looked for my domain in who.is, but no important information in there. I google this problem and someone says that I have to delete my old host. It works.

Why? Is isn't that in theory, once I have switch my nameserver to default, the new host should indicate that my domain isn't hosted in any host, right?

Comment: You need to change the name servers are your registrar to the nameservers of your new host, or adjust the records at your registrar so that they'll point to your new hosting company.

Comment: No, that's can only be done after you register succesffuly a new host. During the registeration, you need to provide the domain

Comment: A hosting company should not *require* a domain name. If you're hosting your website with a different company than you registered the domain with, you need a way for your domain to "map" to the IP address where you're hosting your content. The default nameservers at your registrar will not know where you're hosting your content unless you specify that by either changing the nameservers to your new hosts nameservers, and telling them that you have that domain. Or by adding records at the registrar's nameservers indicating that your content is hosted at the new hosts IP address(an A record)

Comment: Well, so far, I have tried three hosting services, and all of them require my domain to be freed before registering their hosts. Only after that, I could know the IP address of the host so that I can go to the domain registrar to map it to the host (change the nameserver)